# The compression JavaScript file failed from using Combres DLL in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, yui-compressor

I have used Combres Dll to compress the javascript file but an exception occurred i. e. **"EcmaScript.NET.EcmaScriptRuntimeException"**
Combres.xml file code is below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
  This file contains basic settings needed for most web apps.
  For full Combres settings (with explanation), refer to the sample definition file: combres_full_with_annotation.xml
  Also, refer to Combres' documentation: http://combres.codeplex.com/documentation  
-->
<combres xmlns='urn:combres'>
  <filters>
    <filter type="Combres.Filters.FixUrlsInCssFilter, Combres" />
  </filters>
  <resourceSets url="~/combres.axd"
                defaultDuration="30"
                defaultVersion="auto"
                defaultDebugEnabled="false"
                defaultIgnorePipelineWhenDebug="true"
                localChangeMonitorInterval="30"
                remoteChangeMonitorInterval="60"
                >
    <resourceSet name="siteCss" type="css">
      <resource path="~/content/bootstrap.css" />
      <resource path="~/content/Site.css" />
    </resourceSet>
    <resourceSet name="siteJs" type="js">
      <resource path="~/scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
    </resourceSet>
  </resourceSets>
</combres>
```

**Note** *It easily compresses all CSS files but returns the above exception when compressing JavaScript files.*

I tried different versions of Combres Dll but every version return the same exception.

I expect that my JavaScript file easily compress using Combres Dll or any alternative way to compress JavaScript files.
I expect a suitable and accurate solution.